# Unexpected behaviour calling function from function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Recently I started learning about JS, and I got stuck in the following issue:

I am trying to call a function "draw_point" when a "mousemove" event happens.

When trying the following, the code works as expected (the function gets called):

```
    svg.on('mousemove', draw_point(true));
```

But when replacing the caller function like this, it stops working and I don't get any error messages to troubelshoot.

```
    svg.on('mousemove', function () {
        draw_point;
    });
```

Any explanation of what is going on?

Comment: In the first case you *execute* `drawPoint` and pass in the parameter `true`. Note that unless that returns a function, it will just be executed *once* and it happens *immediately* - it will not be assigned as a handler. In the second case, you create a function but never execute `drawPoint`. It's valid code to mention the function reference there but it does nothing at all, since it's not invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are wrong, but for different reasons. In the first, you're calling the function`draw_point` immediately and passing its return value to the `.on` call. In the second, you're creating an anonymous function that wraps `draw_point`, but you're not calling `draw_point`. This is legal because javascript allows empty statements like `myVar;` or `3;`.

What you want to do is pass the function `draw_point`, but not call it. It will be called when the handler runs:

```
svg.on('mousemove', draw_point);
```

Comment: Many thanks! Then what would be the syntax to run multiple functions when the 'mousemove' is called?

I was hoping to be something like this, but I now I am pretty sure it won't work

    svg.on('mousemove', function () {
        draw_point;
        draw_line;
    });

Comment: You're welcome! What you've suggested will also work, you just need to put parenthesis to actually call the functions, like `function () { draw_point(); draw_line(); }`